# Fatal error on PHP prepare()

Tags: php

This is part of my PHP code, which is showing the error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in /../EditAdminRestaurantes.php on line 61
```

Here the code:

```
         <?php

        $id=$_GET['id'];
line 61-> $result = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbrestaurantes WHERE id_restaurante= :userid");
        $result->bindParam(':userid', $id);
        $result->execute();
        for($i=0; $row = $result->fetch(); $i++){
    ?>
```

I have checked the table name and it is ok: tbrestaurantes, the field id_restaurante is also ok.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: The initialization of `$db` has failed.

Comment: Non-Object sounds like $db isn't being set up properly. Connection issue, Username, Password, Permissions perhaps?

Comment: @Fluffeh, that should be the problem, $db should be $dbh, as it is defined in the database connection script. Thank you, I am new to PDO....

Comment: @LucM  , that should be the problem, $db should be $dbh, as it is defined in the database connection script. Thank you, I am new to PDO....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Providing an answer based on the commentary leading to solving the problem:

```
 <?php

    $id=$_GET['id'];
    $result = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbrestaurantes WHERE id_restaurante= :userid");
    $result->bindParam(':userid', $id);
    $result->execute();
    for($i=0; $row = $result->fetch(); $i++)
    {
        // etc etc
?>
```

The database object `$db` was incorrectly being called when it was actually supposed to be `$dbh`.

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort.